# how to stop image responsive in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using twitter bootstrap to making responsive layout.It works like awesome.

It makes images too responsive. I need some images only need to be fixed width and height.

```
<div class="span1"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/uGBKzIY4mpc/0.jpg" width="50" height="40"></div>
```

How can i make it?

Comment: I don't think width="50" height="40" will validate unless you have a time machine back to 1994.

Comment: @PJBrunet and why would '<img width="50" height="40"' not validate since 1994 ??

Comment: @MilchePatern Because I'm pretty sure that's HTML 1.x style code that is considered obsolete. I'd recommend CSS to resize images. Maybe "width=" is used by old email readers that can't handle CSS, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @PJBrunet  W3 specs does NOT consider it obsolete. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked.

```
.fixed_width {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

<div class="span1"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/uGBKzIY4mpc/0.jpg" class="fixed_width" ></div>
```

Comment: oh nice. that's simpler than my solution

Answer (score 14):

Create a new class and set the min height and min-width equal to the width and height of the image that you don't want to shrink, and add that class to those images.

eg.

```
/* css */
img.no-resize {
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 50px;
}

/* html */

<div class="span1">
  <img class="no-resize" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/uGBKzIY4mpc/0.jpg" width="50" height="40">
</div>
```

Comment: I really hope this isn't the "right" way to do it.  First of all, a class is meant to affect multiple items.  Ids are for specific changes, like sizing one specific image.  But what bothers me more: rather than leave an image alone (with no style) it's accosted by Bootstrap and then you're weirdly reverse-engineering Bootstrap to undo the damage--that doesn't seem like an elegant solution.  And isn't this forgetting max-width and max-height?

Answer (score 4):

Check your code make sure that by setting image's width and height attributes `like you did` it's not working and there is an interference in the styling to fix:

```
<div class="span1">
    <img height="40" width="50" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/uGBKzIY4mpc/0.jpg" />
</div>
```

Your image is not supposed to resize with Bootstrap if you correctly fill in width and height attributes. The inlined attributes have precedence over css.

Otherwise, you have to OVERWRITE the img styling from bootstrap.css (line ~68 version 2.0.)

```
img {
  /* Responsive images (ensure images don't scale beyond their parents) */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */
  width: auto\9;
  /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */
  height: auto;
  /* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching */
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Create a css selector with your specifications :

```
/* css */
.max-resize-50x40 {
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
.resize-50x40 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: "*Your image is not supposed to resize with Bootstrap if you correctly fill in width and height*" -- Fwiw, at least in Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m with Bootstrap v3.3.7, if the browser window gets smaller than the image, the image will resize, even when the `height` and `width` are explicitly set (to be clear, this is with no other CSS-related changes -- further setting `min-width` & height keeps it static on smaller resize.)

Answer (score -1):

Even simpler, you should be able to just add a generic class to the image so you can use it on multiple image sizes...

```
/* html */
<img src="image.jpg" alt="An image" class="fixed-size" />

/* css * /
img.fixed-size { height: auto; width: auto; }
```

I haven't tried it in IE but it works on Safari, FF and Chrome.