# can we make some images unresponsive i.e. no effect of re-sizing of browser window in a bootstrap responsive site? I can't find any thing?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

can we make some images unresponsive i.e. no effect of resizing of browser window in a bootstrap responsive site?
I can't find any help?

Comment: You didn't check properly. Did you check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719649/how-to-stop-image-responsive-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Images in Twiiter Bootstrap are not responsive unless appended with the class `img-responsive` so just remove that class from the `img` tag and the image will not be responsive.

**RESPONSIVE:**

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image" />
```

**NON-RESPONSIVE:**

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" alt="image" />
```